# How to turn a single column into three?

Tags: text-formatting

How may I distribute a single column of data over three columns?

Input:

```
A
B
C
A
B
C
.
.
.
```

I want the following result:

```
A B C
A B C
A B C
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 4):

Given the input data exactly as written in the question in the file called `file`, you can use `paste` like this:

```
$ paste - - - <file
A       B       C
A       B       C
.       .       .
```

The output has tabs as field delimiters, but this can be changed with the `-d` option:

```
$ paste -d ' ' - - - <file
A B C
A B C
. . .
```

The three dashes corresponds to the columns in the output and these will be filled by `paste` from one line of input at a time.

See `man paste` on your system.

Answer (score 3):

With `xargs`:

```
$ xargs -n3 < file
A B C
A B C
. . .
```

This outputs at most three arguments per command line. 
Note that I have left out the command to execute which defaults to the `echo` command if missing. It's the same as

```
xargs -n3 echo < file
```

Answer (score 0):

In a very "golfed" form, you can use the following (GNU) `awk` command:

```
awk '{cache=(n%3) ? cache" "$0 : $0; n++; if (n % 3 == 0) {print cache; cache="";}}' inputfile.txt
```

In a more readable form:

```
awk '{if (n%3==0) cache=$0; else cache=cache" "$0; n++; if (n%3==0) {print cache; cache="";}}' inputfile.txt
```

This `awk` program uses an internal line counter `n` (implicitly initalized to 0, which is important), and an internal caching variable `cache` used to accumulate the content of three lines, separated by space (`" "`), and "flush" the cache every three lines.

You can tune to your needs by replacing the `3` and the `" "` in `cache=cache" "$0` it a different line count and "line-token-separator" are needed.